# Braintree subscription in gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, subscription, braintree

I'm using Gravity Form with Braintree Add-on, What I want to do is to add Subscription via credit card payment. when I go to forms->setttings->braintree there is only one option in Transaction Type -> Products and services there is no option for subscription, I searched this from here -> https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/recurring-billing

but It doesn't work for me.

Please help me about this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Gravity Forms with a developer plugin I'd recommend you submit a ticket to them, their support is excellent.  Then come back and add your own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

After a long time searching I found something great.
Just call your Environment,Merchant Key, Public Key and Private Key in functions.php

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment($transaction); //Sandbox OR Products
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId($merchant_key); //Your Braintree Merchant Key
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey($public_key);    //Your Braintree Public Key
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey($private_key);  //Your Braintree Private Key

add_action("gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2);

function after_submission($entry, $form)
{
    //Create Customer
    $result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
        'firstName' => 'First Name',
        'lastName' => 'Last Name',
        'company' => 'Company Name',
        'email' => 'email@email.com',
    ));

    //Get Current Customer ID
    $customer_id = $result->customer->id;

    //Add Customer Credit Card Info to Braintree Subscription
    $result = Braintree_CreditCard::create(array(
        'customerId' => $customer_id,
        'number' => '4111111111111111',
        'expirationDate' => '05/20',
        'cardholderName' => 'Mani'
    ));

    try {

        $customer = Braintree_Customer::find($customer_id);
        $payment_method_token = $customer->creditCards[0]->token;

        //You can add Subscription Package From Braintree Account
        $result = Braintree_Subscription::create(array(
            'paymentMethodToken' => $payment_method_token,
            'planId' => 'Your_subscription_name_here',   
            'price' => '1000'
        ));

        if ($result->success) {
            echo("Success! Subscription " . $result->subscription->id . " is " . $result->subscription->status);
        } else {
            echo("Validation errors:");
            foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
                echo("- " . $error->message);
            }
        }
    } catch (Braintree_Exception_NotFound $e) {
    echo("Failure: no customer found with ID " . $customer_id);
 }
```